# Error when using dojox.mobile.Opener

Tags: dojo

Im trying to use the dojox opener.  I tried running the example straight out of the dojo examples, but when i try to run it it fails with: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'offsetWidth' in undefined

```
<button onclick="dijit.registry.byId('customPicker').show()">slide up</button>
<div id="customPicker" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Opener">
     <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Heading" label="Custom Picker">
          <div data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ToolBarButton" label="Done" class="mblColorBlue" style="width:45px;float:right;" onClick="dijit.registry.byId('customPicker').hide()"></div>
     </h1>
     Hello There!!!
</div>
```

I put an example in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VD9RN/1/

Comment: hmm now works on fiddle, but still can get it to work on my project. same code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem,  When the the screen size is below a certain threshhold dojo uses a slide up method from the bottom.  The example works when this is a case, but if dojo thinks you are in a tablet resolution it uses the tooltip function to show the contents, in this case it was failing.  The tooltip overlay requires the aroundNode argument for the show command.
So i changed the above button to be:

`<button onclick="dijit.registry.byId('customPicker').show(this)">slide up</button>`

And it worked fine in tablet and phone.